# Assigning element's id to variable on .hover() for use in click event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 12 elements on my page(however below I have only written code for 3). When one is clicked, the other 11 disappear(using animation called 'spinOut'). Instead of writing code to run on click for each individual element, I want the the id of the element to be assigned to the `$test` variable upon hovering, and then upon `$test` (the element hovered on) being clicked, my code to be carried out for that element. So I will only have to write out one block of code that will be applied to `$test` which means it will be applied to any element that's been clicked on.

I am trying to assign a value to the variable $test inside the .hover() function and then use it outside. I have found many posts where people have had similar problem but none of the solutions that fixed their problems have helped me. I want to know how can I assign the `$test` variable inside the .hover() function and then use it outside.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $test;

    $("#M").hover(function () {
        $test = "#M";
    });
    $("#N").hover(function () {
        $test = "#N";
    });
    $("#O").hover(function () {
        $test = "#O";
    });

    //When I define variable value here it works
    $($test).click(function () {
        $(".pageItem:not("+$test+")").addClass("spinOut");
    });
});
```

Comment: Variable scope is not the problem here. If you consider what you're trying to do for a second - `$test` will be `''` on load when you attach the `click` event. That's not going to select any elements.

Comment: I tried just doing `var $test` and that didn't work. How do I change the value of $test inside the .hover() function then?

Comment: @Mintblaze the value is being changed, the problem is your click event

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? What's the end goal of this code?

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I have edited my question to state what I'm trying to do.

Comment: If you have 12 elements and you want the clicked one to be kept visible then re-think your logic and work with the clicked element. If there are classes defined in your elements then you can target around `this` elements and hide them. You can add/remove class to selected item and select all other, then hide them. But playing scope in this manner doesn't look very practical.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I, clearly, am not very experienced - its the only method I could think of. I want to be able to have one piece of code that will be applied to whichever element has been clicked on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's how I got it to work. The 12 elements on my page where all part of ".pageItem" class. I don't have to specify the specific element in `$().click` - I just have to run code upon any .pageItem being clicked, then use the `$test` variable inside the function to target the .pageItem that had been clicked on. The code will be applied to the element I last hovered on - impossible to click one of the elements without hovering on them first.

```
$("#M").hover(function () {
    $test = "#M";
});
$("#N").hover(function () {
    $test = "#N";
});
$("#O").hover(function () {
    $test = "#O";
});
$(.pageItem).click(function () {
    $(".pageItem:not("+$test+")").addClass("spinOut");
});
```

However, there is a much simpler and more logical way of doing what I needed. Instead of filling `$test` with the id of the .pageItem I last hovered on and using it to specify what I had clicked on, I assign `$(this).attr("id")` to `$test` inside the .click() function like so:

```
$(.pageItem).click(function () {
    $test = $(this).attr("id");
    $(".pageItem:not("+$test+")").addClass("spinOut");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that this way because when setting up the trigger click the element do not exist (as it is empty). One way to do that:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var $test = '';
        $("#M").hover(function () {
            $test = "#M";
        });

        $(document).on('click', $test, (function () {
            if ($test)
               console.log($test);
        });
});
```

**EDIT**: another way to do that:

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
        var $test = '';
        $("#M").hover(function () {
            // for future use if needed
            $test = "#M";

            $(this).unbind('click').click(function () {
               console.log($test);
            });
        });
});
```

Comment: This has the exact same problem

Comment: You can't do it that way either. When `on` is called `$test` is set to the empty string. `on` will not be called again when `$test` changes.

Comment: It works but not in the way I want. Doing it this way, after the first click I can then click anywhere on the page and the function gets carried out. I need the function to only be executed when the element with the id that `$test` contains is clicked on....if that makes sense

Comment: @Baumi No because I need the function that happens on click to be outside the `.hover()` function

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#M").hover(function () {
        $test = "#M";
        eventClick($test, function() { console.log($test); });
    });

    var eventClick=function(ele, f) {
        $(ele).unbind('click');
        $(ele).click(f);
    };

});
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to only attach a click handler to an element you've hovered over. There are many ways of doing that. Here's one:

```js
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('.clickable').on('mouseenter', function () {
            $(this).data('can-click', true);
        }).on('mouseleave', function () {
            $(this).data('can-click', false);
        });
        $(document).on('click', function (e) {
            var currentTarget = $(e.target);
            if (currentTarget.data('can-click')) {
                 console.log('clicked');
            }
        });
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="M" class="clickable">M</div>
<div id="O">O</div>
```

Technically, this listens to any click event on the whole document, but only reacts to those that are being hovered over. It works by marking the elements which are "clickable" as available for clicking only when hovered over. When the user clicks, the code checks for that mark before continuing the code.

Answer (score 0):

Just assuming your clickable items are "input" of type "button" you could do something like this, possibly.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var $test = '';
    $("#M").hover(function () {
        $test = "#M";
    });

    $("input[type=button]").on('click', function (e) {
        console.log($test);
    });
});
```

If my assumption is incorrect, then this possible solution may not work or may need to be changed.

Just a thought